# Fighting WIF for my own IPrincipal in an MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, wif, acs

I want to add Azure ACS to one of my sites, but having issues with all of the magic. I have an MVC app that uses a global filter to set a custom IPrincipal for the life of the request. The problem with the "add STS reference" methodology of WIF is that it short circuits this via an HttpModule.

This much I know: ACS bounces back to my Web app to the URL I configured it for, and that bounce is a POST with the normalized SAML token. I'm not interested in WIF setting cookies or any of that nonsense... I just want to get the claims I'm interested in from the POST and deal with setting auth stuff up myself from there. What's the workflow? The documentation is lousy, and focuses on the magic "right click" solution.

Comment: Why do you not want the cookies to be set?

Comment: Because I don't want to replace the session tracking and user identification I already have in place.

Comment: Check my answer in the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285158/azure-acs-without-the-generated-code-and-httphandlers/7890673#7890673) where I talk about your very issue. The answer you marked as accepted is one of the 3 solutions I proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a really easy solution to your problem:

Register on the `SecurityTokenValidated` event of the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule`, set `e.Cancel` to `true` and start your sign in logic with the information provided in the `ClaimsPrincipal` property of the event args.

Setting `Cancel` to `true` on the event args prevents WIF from creating any IPrincipal or session, so you can handle this stuff by your self.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of using WIF + MVC, with different levels of control. I would suggest these ones: http://claimsid.codeplex.com or the ones in the Identity Training Kit.

WIF pretty much takes care of everything for you. For deeper extensibility, you should check Vittorio's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185).

Regarding: *I just want to get the claims I'm interested in from the POST and deal with setting auth stuff up myself from there.*

What would you want to do yourself that WIF doesn't? What functionality would you include in your ***IPrincipal*** that ***IClaimsPrincipal*** doesn't provide?

There are many knobs and levers in WIF with all kind of fine grain control. It would probably help if you share what is it you want to do.

Comment: It's an existing application. I don't want to change any of the auth plumbing beyond identifying a user at the start of a session. The P&P site on Codeplex is not useful.

This, by the way, is what annoys me about too many of our frameworks... they always "take care of everything." With most non-trivial work, that's usually the last thing developers want.

Comment: Sorry, I need more info to understand what you are trying to do. What does "auth" mean? Authentication or Authorization? Is your app using role based security? are you using ASP.NET membership? custom database? Active Directory? Does your application rely on HttpContext.Current.User? Are you OK with just replacing authentication, but keeping authorization? Do you use the [Authorize] attribute in MVC? do you use session? Is this a web farm?

Comment: I'm not using any of the ASP.NET mechanisms beyond setting a formsauth cookie and an MVC global filter to hydrate the IPrincipal (HttpContext User). And it is at times used in a Web farm (Azure instances), so I'm not using session state. The only piece of the app I want to replace is the login, so instead of verifying credentials against the db and setting forms auth, the verified credentials should come from ACS, once. Roles are not important either.